# Give error when save Data on sqllight using HTML5

Tags: html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function init() {

                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
            }

            function queryDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
            }
            function querySuccess(tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                alert("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
                }
            }


            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
            }

            function successCB() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            }


            function onDeviceReady() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

            }

        </script>


    </head>
    <body onload="init();" >
        <a  onclick="onDeviceReady();"></a>


    </body>

</html>
```

I run Above Code To save Data On Android Tab (I take That Code From phone gap web site).But When I try above code I get following error.I run Above code on Android tab.Can you u help me to solve this problem.

```
0-29 16:27:57.955: E/Web Console(3813): Uncaught ReferenceError: onDeviceReady is not    defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:1
```

Comment: Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/KYknS/3/ , although don't understand why the method is considered undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `<script>` to the body. If it's in head it doesn't get evaluated before the onload of the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/KYknS/4/

Comment: Now i get follwing error.10-29 17:37:32.890: E/Web Console(2692): Uncaught ReferenceError: successCB is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:65

Comment: Did you mode all the code in the body? Can you show me the code that produce the error?

Comment: Thnax Can you tell me what is difference between corodova 3.1 and phone gap 2.9

Comment: Search google or post new question, don't know those.